# How to configure weblogic web service for autostart with server?

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper, weblogic12c

I have created a web service and deployed it on web logic server 12c (12.1.2) as .war file from Jdeveloper. Web service works good after each deployment. But when I restart server and send request to web service then it returns HTTP Error 403. Each and every time I need to go in my Jdeveloper and deploy this web service again and again to make it work.

Is there any way to start this web service automatically as web logic server starts?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting a 403 (Forbidden) and not 404 (Not found) response..? because it's a totally different thing..

Did you have any issue or errors raised during deployment ..?

Regarding starting a deployment with weblogic server start up, it depends on the last status of the deployment before the server was shutdown. So if the deployment was in a state "Active" then you shutdown the server, then when you start the server the deployment would start with the server, or at least try to if there wasn't any errors or so.
If the deployment was in a state of "Prepared", then when the server restarts, it won't start that deployment.

Regards,
Mohab

Comment: Yes, I am getting 403, and I am sure there are no issues during deployment. Every morning when I start work I deploy web service, then I work for whole day and in evening I shutdown web logic. Then same process I need to follow with new morning.

Comment: I am new to Web Logic and it is a fresh installation. May be there is some configuration setting to achieve this.

Comment: A 403 response means that your request is understood, but there was a security configuration that "Denied" you from accessing, so it doesn't mean that your application is down, while a 404 might indeed indicates that the application is not running.

So maybe you're not using the correct URL to access/call the web service, or you are enforcing some kind of application policies that is denying you from access.

Comment: Yes, every time I gets this message '403 Request was understood by server but it is not able to fulfill it'. My URL is right as the same URL works after new deployment. Now the only posiblity is that configuration which I am missing.

Comment: Have you checked the logs ..? what does they say about the error ..?

Comment: Error logs says 403, may be this is causing because I am using web logic in production mode. I just read that in production mode, applications are not auto deploy-able. Applications remain in prepared mode and we need to make them start. I think my war application is in prepared mode when I start web logic server and this is causing 403. Am I right?

Comment: I don't think so. If your application was in a Prepared state (not mode), then you'd get a 404 response when trying to access it.

In weblogic production mode, it's true that the application state just after a deployment is set to Prepared, but if you started that application, then restarted the server, it would start in Active state, not Prepared (if nothing else went wrong of course)